How to Send Data to Mouse via Bluetooth Using a Script?
I recently purchased a Logitech MX Master 3S mouse, which can connect to three devices: one via USB and two via Bluetooth. The issue I face is that the switching button is located at the bottom of the mouse, and I would prefer to automate the switching process with a script.
When I am connected via USB, I can successfully switch between devices using the following command:

hidapitester.exe --vidpid 046D:C548 --usage 0x0001 --usagePage 0xFF00 --open --length 7 --send-output 0x10,0x02,0x0a,0x1b,0x01,0x00,0x00

However, this command does not work when I try to switch the connection to Bluetooth. I have attempted various tools like btcom, but none of them seem capable of sending data to Bluetooth devices.
Is there any way I can achieve this via a script? Specifically, I want to send the following data to the Bluetooth device:

0x10,0x02,0x0a,0x1b,0x00,0x00,0x00

Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

The problem is that your "Bluetooth device" is just for you one entity. On Bluetooth level it is divided into services and inside each service you have multiple characteristics where each of them can have a different functionality (read/write notify). For functions standardized by Bluetooth SIG you need to read the documentationmto understand what data you need to send where but proprietary functions like input switching is a bit difficult. By chance you will not make this work.

I assume the mouse is using BLE, therefore a tool like BLEConsole should allow you to "talk" to your device.
